# checking a colum based on anther colum in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a forum that is saved to a mysql database the table for the actual posts is `call _discuss_posts`
In here I have the ID of the post and another column `call parent_id` (there are loads more but those are the two columns that are of interest to me.)

So basically all replies and new posts are added to this table if it is a reply it has a `parent_id` that corresponds to the first post ID.

Now, this is where I'm getting confused. I'm trying to count the number of replies each ID has, I could do:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `qwt1v_discuss_posts` WHERE `parent_id`=4968
```

But I don't want to manually change the `parent_id` each time, there is over 10k post.

So my question is this, I'm trying to figure out if there is a query I can do to automatically count based off of the ID. So for example, the first row ID is 2000 and I want to check all the other rows in the column `parent_id` to find the ones that are allocated to the ID 2000 once I get to the end of the table, move to the next row to grab the next ID value lets say ID value 2001 and do a search for the that in the column parent_id.

Hopefully i made some sence as its a all jumbled up in my own head so apologies if i havn't been very clear.

Right now i'm trying to simply find an SQL query but eventualy i will be moving to a php script so that i can show this in a table for some dashboards.

Thanks to whom ever reads this

Best

Comment: Can you explain the scenario clearly?

Comment: The plan is to be able to make a simple table to help the moderator of the forum to see what kind of past posts have had the most engagement and then create moderated discussions around those topics.

Answer (score 1):

if you need the count of each `parent_id`  you should use group by eg:

```
  SELECT `parent_id`, count(*) 
  FROM `qwt1v_dis, uss_posts` 
  group by `parent_id`
```